# Multiple instances of `webapp-container`?

Tags: webapps

In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop [`webapp-container`](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/web/ubuntu-webapps-guide/) is a handy way to launch web apps in a standalone browser:

```
webapp-container --name=FirstWebApp https://firstwebapp.com
```

However if, while FirstWebApp is running, I desire to open SecondWebApp and run the following command:

```
webapp-container --name=SecondWebApp https://secondwebapp.com
```

I am given the message `Passing arguments to already running instance`, focus is sent to FirstWebApp and nothing else happens.

Is there a way to force another `webapp-container` to open instead?

I note that [this merge](https://code.launchpad.net/~osomon/webbrowser-app/single-application/+merge/282961) into `webbrowser-app` appears to be the source of this behaviour, but I'm not familiar enough with the project to see if there's a way to override the single-instance enforcement.

Comment: Can you please amend your question to include details of the device and environment you are using.

Comment: Thanks Tony, I have added that it's the Desktop version of Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Apparently a [known bug #1579195](https://bugs.launchpad.net/webapp-container/+bug/1579195) in `webapp-container`

Comment: Add yourself to the bug.  That will increase the 'heat' and the chance that someone will do something about it.